# GIT Branching issues and how to resolve

Tags: git, branch

If I created a branch(issue#1) from the master to fix the one issue.

I have been working on the mater for sometime and did couple of changes to master, when I have created branch (issue#1), this branch will have the master commits also (assume i will commit my changes to master on daily basis).

But I have to fix the issue on the master original. How can I go forward?

Comment: Typically you would merge your issue branch back into master. That's the point of making such branches.

Comment: Are you facing some problem in branching or merging? Sounds like you already know the basic stuff. Make sure to have a clean state before branching or merging.

Comment: I am facing issue with merging. What ever work i have done on master those commits are local, when create branch even those changes will be part of my branch.

Comment: `git checkout master` followed by `git merge issue#1` should do the work for you.